# Proving $|\cos f(x) - \cos g(x)| \leq |f(x)-g(x)|$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Apparently this can be done using the fact that $\cos x$ is a contraction mapping on (0,1).

That is, there is some $\theta \in (0,1)$ for which

$$
||\cos x - \cos y||\leq \theta ||x-y||
$$
for any norm on $C([0,1])$. My professor suggested to "use the mean value theorem" as well, but I am unsure how to apply it.

Additionally, this is supposed to really be true for any contraction mapping $\phi$, so we could just write
$$
|\phi(f(x))-\phi(g(x))|\leq \theta|f(x)-g(x)|
$$
in generality.

Comment: Have you thought about using the mean value theorem? It's a strong hint for homework, and it's not clear from your question what you've attempted so far.

Comment: yes, this is indeed an immediate consequence of the mean value theorem, and a little known fact about $\sin \theta$. Do show your attempt.

Comment: I realized that this can be seen from the fact that $\cos x$ is Lipschitz. In particular, we know that $|\cos f(x) - \cos g(x)| \leq K |f(x)-g(x)|$ with $K=\sin 1=\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |(\cos x)'|$.

Comment: How do you know how big the values $f[x)$ and $g(x)$ can be?